# Bump + Displace Map - Weird Result

Tags: materials, displacement, bump

I'm rendering a scene with a material that has a bump + displace map. At 4096 samples, why do I see this happening? The mesh it's applied to has a subdvision surface modifier applied to it

https://snipboard.io/8HZxWV.jpg

https://snipboard.io/ZNbzTw.jpg

Comment: could you please pack your images and share your file?

Comment: Uploaded to weTransfer: https://we.tl/t-9awJBrk8tW @moonboots

Comment: it is super heavy, could you please only share the useful part?

Comment: ok I've opened it, it's not clear what and on which texture is your problem, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Comment: @moonboots Sorry I only have this version, the texture in question is called "Brick Wall" and it's applied to the mesh Cube.002

Comment: it makes my blender crash, i hope someone will understand

Comment: I think the wall needs to be subdivided more for it to work properly. The problem is that the "edges" around the wall are much more subdivided than the "front" and "back" so subdividing it further will add insane (unmanageable) numbers of faces around the outer edges. I suggest you use a _Decimate Modifier_ set to _Planar_ to remove all the unnecessary subdivisions, then add horizontal and vertical subdivisions via loopcuts before subdividing again. Do not add any loop cuts around the outer edges. Subdivide the whole thing 20x or so, then subdiv surface level 3 or 4 should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your subdivision does not provide enough vertices to make good use of the displacement. I think the displacement map is high-res enough to push the individual bricks forward, but it only has 2.5 vertices to work with in the verical direction. Adding two more levels of subdivision will likely help here.

Also, the mesh could use some smooth shading - the current one accentuates the sharp corners, making the issue above more apparent.